# UINavigationController becomes null when using pushViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit

I have a little problem using `UINavigationController`.

I have a first `ViewController (called LaunchViewController)` with a navigation controller (that works fine), I can use `pushViewController` to display a `second ViewController (called SettingViewController)` and it works fine too, but when (from the first view controller) I want to display a third `ViewController (called IPhonePage),` after the view is displayed, and when I want to use the `navigation controller` in my `IPhonePage`, the `navigation controller` is `null...`

Don't know if my question is clear, I can show you the code I use to do that :

`AppDelegate.m :`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    LaunchViewController* controller = [[LaunchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LaunchViewController" bundle:nil];
    _navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
    _navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.window setRootViewController:_navigationController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

`LaunchViewController.m :`

```
- (IBAction)showSettings:(id)sender {
    SettingViewController* controller = [[SettingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

This works fine (I can access the `navigation controller` in `SettingViewController)`

But this,

`LaunchViewController.m :`

```
- (void)ShowPageWithIMDevicePage:(id<IMDevicePage>)page {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:(UIViewController*)page animated:YES];
}
```

The page is created by :

```
- (id<IMDevicePage>)CreatePage {
    return [[IPhonePage alloc] init];
}
```

And my IPhonePage class looks like this,

IPhonePage.h :

```
@interface IPhonePage : UIViewController <IMDevicePage>
```

IPhonePage.m :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"navigation controller = %@", self.navigationController);
}
```

And the log displays **navigation controller = (null)**, e.g. I don't have access to the `navigation controller.`

I really hope someone's gonna understand what I want, I know it's a bit complicated but it's for a specific reason that I make that this way.

Thanks ! Cheers :)

**EDIT**
Actually it happens because I create the page, and I set different things like the title, content and toolbar, and then I call `pushViewController`, the strange thing is that I have a method that sets the content of the UIViewController

`IPhonePage.m`

```
- (void)SetContentWithIMDeviceControl:(id<IMDeviceControl>)content {
    self.view = (UIView*)content;
}
```

And after that it doesn't call anymore my viewDidLoad method (any clue ?).
Also I have a method which role is to add a toolbar at the bottom of the view

```
- (void)SetApplicationBarWithIMDeviceApplicationBar:(id<IMDeviceApplicationBar>)appBar {
}
```

At first I wanted to use the navigation controller to set this toolbar, but because this method is called before the `pushViewController` method, the navigation controller is nil.
Is there any possibility to set manually the navigation controller without calling `pushViewController` ? Or any other way to add a toolbar ? Like declaring a toolbar and adding it as a subview maybe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like :

```
- (void)ShowPageWithIMDevicePage:(id<IMDevicePage>)page {
    YourDelegate* delegate = (YourDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    IPhonePage* pageVC = (IPhonePage*)page;
    [delegate.navigationController pushViewController:pageVC animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: What happens ? It does anything ? It pushes a white page ?
Try to NSLog something of your IPhonePage. Something like NSLog (@"test iphone page : %@", page.testable_attribute) and tell us if the log seems to be correct.

Comment: It displays the content (an UITableView) and it sets the Title, so it's working. I just can't get access to the navigationController ...

Comment: I edited my answer changing IPhonePage* page -> IPhonePage* pageVC and push the pageVC, not the page. It's just to clarify my first answer and to not get a conflict between id<IMDevicePage> parameter and IPhonePage object.

Comment: Try NSLog(@"delegate VC : %@", [delegate.navigationController class]).  It seems to log UINavigationController. I don't understand why pushing a page with the navigationcontroller delegate doesn't work :/

Comment: I putted the log in my ShowPageWithIMDevicePage method and I get this : UINavigationController so it seems that it's ok, right ?

Comment: Try this :
UIViewController* controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
controller.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[delegate.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

Comment: Yeah, that displays a red view, but still I can't get the navigation controller in my instance of IPhonePage :/

Comment: I think you may change the way to create this view controller. 
Sorry, I can't do more.

Comment: And please, a little +1 for the answers ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can access self.navigationController in - (void)viewWillAppear function. When you create the UIViewController, - (void)viewDidLoad is called. And at this time, you haven't called the pushViewController function and thus self.navigationController is not set.